# Python 3 - Plotting a mapplotlib graph from dictionary pairs

Tags: python, list, dictionary, matplotlib, graph

I’m new to python - I’ve set myself some exercises with statistics to get to grips with the syntax. This particular one is to graph the outcome of a number of throws of two dice.

I’ve created a list of my throws, then a dictionary to map the total throws for each outcome for all possible values 2-12. I now want to plot the frequency of this using pyplot. I’ve copied it back to a list to sort in order, but I can’t think of a way to extract the totals to plot -only- them on the graph. The code below gives a line for the totals, and a straight line for the corresponding keys of 2 to 12. I assume I’m probably being overly laborious here, so any hints would be appreciated.

Thanks, Sarah

```
from matplotlib import pyplot 
from random import *
diceTotal = []
totThrows = dict()
i = 0
numThrows = 100

#Create data
for i in range(numThrows):
  diceTotal.append(randint(1,6) + randint(1,6))

#Store totals
for dice in diceTotal:
  totThrows[dice] = totThrows.get(dice,0) + 1

#Sort totals by key
listThrows = list(totThrows.items())
listThrows.sort()

plotThrows = list(listThrows)
print(plotThrows)
pyplot.plot(plotThrows) 
pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]Your question is not clear. But if you want to extract the information in `plotThrows` simply iterate on them as below;

```
xvals = [x[0] for x in plotThrows]
yvals = [x[1] for x in plotThrows]
```

one way would be to plot as scatter plot;

```
pyplot.scatter(xvals, yvals)
pyplot.show()
```

I hope that was your question. Otherwise, you should clarify your question to get an answer.

Comment: Thanks for that - apologies for not communicating effectively. The key line I was missing was the way to extract the second coordinate for each value:

yvals = [x[1] for x in plotThrows]

This allowed me to plot only these values. - More importantly, it shows how I extract values from arrays of dictionary items.